# Catch Android random crashes tips

Tags: android, testing, random, crash

My testing team complains that they experience random crashes in my Android app that they cannot reproduce. What is the best way to know the cause of these crashes? 
Flurry and other analytics tools don't send the whole crash log to me, they send only a few lines that don't help.

What is the best way to catch the cause these random crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very good thing you can do is set your own [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for main UI thread and send all info you need to your webservice or to GoogleAlalytics(v.2 Analytics has such feature for Android devices).

If you do not have your own webservice you could integrate third party service like [HockeApp](http://hockeyapp.net). It perform pretty much the same opperations but works "from the box" and you need to write only one line of code in your app.

Hope it help you!

Answer (score 2):

I think they have to use a LogCat application from the Play Store. For example:
[aLogcat (free) - logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat). After a crash they can view the LogCat information and share with you.

Comment: Note: This doesn't work on Jelly Bean (4.1+) due to changes in permissions for reading the system logs. Any users on 4.1 or higher will have to use `Power + Vol Up + Vol Down` down, or will have to root and set the app to run as a system app.

Comment: Thanks for the completion.